# HTML form losing its values when submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to submit a HTML form that has some values created via javascript. However, when I submit the form those input fields lose their values in favor of empty strings. What can I do to prevent the fields from dropping their new values upon hitting the submit button?

Form Code:

```
<form id="post-form" class="save-form" method="POST" action="/posts" style="display: none">
  <input placeholder="Title" name="title" /><br>
  <input placeholder="Location" name="location" /></br>
  <input placeholder="Content" name="content" /><br>

  <input id="formlat" name="latitude" type="hidden" />
  <input id="formlng" name="longitude" type="hidden" />      
  <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<%= current_user.id %>" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Relevant Javascript Code:

```
  var newlat = newmarker.getPosition().lat();
  var newlng = newmarker.getPosition().lng();

  document.getElementById("formlat").value = newlat;
  document.getElementById("formlng").value = newlng;
```

Setting default values, or not setting them, always produces the same result: the form submits with "" for those fields (or whatever was inside value=""). However, the console shows that those fields are correctly being filled with their lat/long up until I hit the submit button, where they revert to their default values (in this case ""). It is only in rails' logs that I can see the fields are blank in the actual POST.

The user id field, however, does keep its value when submitting. So I believe the form is overwriting its value fields upon hitting the submit button. Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will need to provide more code, possibly a [mcve].

Comment: Please use a document ready function

Comment: @SithLee what would the use of document ready serve OP here? They have already mentioned using the console for verification, so if there was a dom readiness issue they would see error messages about that code.

Comment: Okay then I can assume that forms should be keeping values assigned with js script as their default behavior? I will read the MCV docs and update the post when I have a model of it.